# How to PXE network boot a Ubuntu Server 12.04 using HTTP

Tags: 12.04, boot, pxe

I have a task to PXE install Ubuntu servers by HTTP,
so I find the tutor in [PXEInstallServer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) and [KickstartCompatibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility) and set my PXE server as it said.
Then I open a test client and which can get a IP address successfully and get into the PXE install screen, but when I select the "pxe-ubuntu" to install by HTTP, it goes smooth at first but after the step of "Configuring network with DHCP", it shows nothing but a black screen with a white blank blinking at the left bottom.

Here are some configure files.

```
$ cat /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default 
label pxe-ubuntu
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append ks=http://192.168.20.20/ks.cfg vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
    ramdisk_size=16432 root=/dev/rd/0 rw  --

root@test1:~# cat /var/www/ks.cfg 
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone Asia/Shanghai
#Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$MT0GPRHy$cEcpS63J6JNZ5j.gsp/Yv0
#Initial user
user a --fullname "" --iscrypted --password $1$7Ttd.gsK$WMV9UGm/S.sHOruaD4LPf0
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use Web installation
url --url http://10.10.20.20/ubuntu/install/
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 200 
part / --fstype xfs --size 10240 
part swap --size 4096 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled 
#X Window System configuration information
xconfig --depth=8 --resolution=1024x768 --defaultdesktop=GNOME
```

Comment: The typing "http:/ /" is for avoiding the sentence to be a url.

Comment: URLs won't be converted inside code blocks, so there's no need to do that.

Comment: Ever solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, already solved. ;) @nbubis

Comment: @Nidhoggur , Would you please share the solution you got by writing an an answer to this. See http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer